# stable baselines action space

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

How to have multiple action space in stable baseline. My action space is a combination of Discrete and Box. I have tried gym.spaces.Tuple([gym.spaces.Discrete(5), gym.spaces.Box(low=0.001, high=1.0, shape=(1,))]) and gym.spaces.Dict but script seems to freeze without any error or warnings. I am using PPO2 from sb3

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately stable-baselines 3 doesn't work with dictionaries (or tuples).
You can only work with Box, Discrete, MultiDiscrete and MultiBinary